# slurm_load_partitions:Unable to contact slurm controller

Tags: controller, slurm

I had this problem using the slurm command.Unable to contact slurm controller.
this is part of my slurm.conf:

```
########################################
# YHPC NAME
########################################
ClusterName=yhstar
########################################
# BASIC INFO
########################################
#ControlAddr=192.168.251.230
ControlMachine=kylin1
#BackupAddr=mn1
#BackupController=mn1
#ReconfigFlags=
#SlurmUser=root
#SlurmdUser=root
#SlurmctldPort=6817
#SlurmdPort=6818
#DynAllocPort=
TreeWidth=50
```

this is part of my node.conf:

```
NodeName=kylin1 NodeAddr=192.168.251.230 State=UNKNOWN Sockets=8 CoresPerSocket=4
```

this is part of my partition.conf:

```
PartitionName=work Nodes=kylin1 Default=YES State=UP MaxTime=INFINITE
```